# NextJs 13 & Framer Motion: Module not found: Can't resolve 'v8'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

Keep getting this error, I have my `app directory` and trying to animate page transitions but  whatever I do with framer motion I keep getting this v8 error. Cannot find many things around it, does anyone have any solution for it?

```
'use client';

import { Poppins } from '@next/font/google';
import { useRouter, React } from 'react';
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import { getSession } from '../lib/session';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import AuthContext from '../components/AuthContext';
import '../styles/globals.css';

// If loading a variable font, you don't need to specify the font weight
const poppins = Poppins({
  weight: '500',
});

export default async function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const session = await getSession();
  const router = useRouter();
  return (

    <html lang="en" className={poppins.className}>
      <head />
      <body>

        <AuthContext session={session}>
          <Header />
          <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
            <motion.div
              key={router.route}
              initial="initialState"
              animate="animateState"
              exit="exitState"
              transition={{
                duration: 0.75,
              }}
              variants={{
                initialState: {
                  opacity: 0,
                  clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)',
                },
                animateState: {
                  opacity: 1,
                  clipPath: 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)',
                },
                exitState: {
                  clipPath: 'polygon(50% 0, 50% 0, 50% 100%, 50% 100%)',
                },
              }}
            >
              {children}
            </motion.div>
          </AnimatePresence>
        </AuthContext>
        {session ? <Footer /> : ''}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Maybe it has to do with nextAuth? Not sure

[image]

Comment: I think that your problem has something to do with calling framerMotion on server side, because v8 is engine of browser... but unfortunately i havent used framer motion with react yet...

Comment: @Wraithy I added `'use client';` on top which makes it a client rendered component, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: The error clearly originates from 'next-auth/next' by import of '../lib/session'. Did you try upgrading your next-auth version? Can you add the contents of 'lib/session' to your post?

Comment: This problem is coming from next-auth. Can you show us what you have in your lib/session folder

Comment: This is usually a problem when you import into your fronted bundle a code that is meant to run on the server only. (v8 is nodejs engine)

Comment: I have the same errors, no one could help i found this and another person with same error in Nextjs 13 app router : https://nextjs-forum.com/post/1121700104877916170

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while googling about can't resolve 'v8'.
Note: I don't use framer-motion, but have a similar can't resolve 'v8' error.

The solution for me was:

1. Full backup of the working directory - for safety ;) In case you want to go back on your changes...
2. In Visual Studio Code's Terminal: npm list
   then note all the version numbers because the following steps may upgrade, even delete parts of the current version!
3. Re-install all the modules on that npm list, one by one.
4. Noticing some vulnerabilities, so used: npm audit fix,
5. Some vulnerabilities remain, so used: npm audit fix --force
6. nmp list
   and compare what changed from step 2.
7. Eventually saw a message that my start page was causing some problem: my previous experiments using app\pages.js and app\layout.js was conflicting with my \index.js
   Both wanted to start the app at the same time.
   There can only be one way to start your app!
   So delete or rename either pages.js + layout.js, or index.js.
8. In the .js file which is the client side / front end fetching the data from the server and displaying the data to the user,
   changed from:

```
    import { withPageAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs';
```

to

```
    import { withPageAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs/client';
```

This step was modified, originally suggested by @blazestudios23 in https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client/discussions/442

Apparently with auth0 from version 2.0.0 there are changes which could break your code... Go read the original post.
Especially so when doing updates to the latest modules (i.e. steps 3 & 4).

I'm using auth0/nextjs-auth0@2.21

9. now: npx run dev
   works OK, ! :)
10. If it doesn't work, restore the backup of your working directory, and attempt another method.

Hope that helped... YMMV All the best!

Answer (score -1):

You can try check if all module imported are installed. I use framer-motion buh I have never seen an error like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

The answer lies in here:

> Can't resolve 'v8'.

So you should add v8 to your project.

```
npm install v8 / yarn add v8
```

Comment: `v8` refers to a builtin, like `fs` and `path` - you cannot install it via npm